Should I prefer `dynamic` or `Object?` for generics in Dart?
I've been trying to understand how I should enforce the strict-raw-types rule from Dart, and make sure my code adheres strictly to the type system.
I understand the difference between dynamic and Object? for variables:

dynamic works like the Typescript any and completely breaks from the type system, i.e. "I don't know, so everything goes" (and therefore should never be used IMO);
while Object? is like Kotlin's Any and more sanely means "I don't know, so nothing goes" (which is perfectly fine).

However, I can't seem to find a lot of resources on what these types should mean when used as Generic type parameters.
Let's say I want something similar to a List<*> in Kotlin, meaning:

it has a type
I don't know the type
"nothing goes"

I can see I can do both List<dynamic> and List<Object?>, and it seems they both behave pretty much the same. Is that the case?
If I "take" an element out of the dynamic list, it has the type dynamic implicitly (vs Object?), but if I try to use it as dynamic it is blocked by the linter already, so not that bad. Still, that sounds like a reason for me to dislike List<dynamic>. I couldn't find any difference when "putting" to the list, both options accept both parameter types.
On the other hand, writing List<Object?> feels weird to me because it seems that I am forcing a specific type (as if I wrote List<Any> on Kotlin), which is not exactly what I want. Specially when added to abstract framework code that doesn't really care about the type of the generics. So I also feel inclined to dislike this option.
Which would be the "recommended" / "preferred" option for those trying to enforce stricter type rules, or are there other options that I am missing? Should one of these options be banned by the linter?

As an example, imagine I have a BoxDumper class that can take and store boxes of any types on a list. The boxes are never retrieved.
class BoxDumper {
  // note that I do not want to tie it to a `T`
  final List<Box<*>> _dump;

  void take(Box<*> box) {
    _dump.add(box);
  }
}


It might help to see an example code where you are running into this problem. In some cases it might be preferable to declare a type argument T and then use List<T>.

@mmcdon20 I 100% agree that whenever possible, a type argument T should be added, but that is not always the case, for example, say I want a List<Box<*>>, where each Box is of a different type. I cannot parametrize that as a single T.

If you understand dynamic vs. Object? for variables, I don't see why generics would be any different.  It's the same thing: using dynamic just disables type-checking for objects of that type.  So for a generic container, if consuming code uses a dynamic element type, then they'll disable type-checking when getting elements back out.

@jamesdlin Which means I definitely don't wanna use List<dynamic>; but I think I also don't want a List<Object?> because that is determining which kind of lists it takes (only object lists). I basically want a List<*> in kt or a List<? extends Object> in java. It could take a List, List, and a List<Object?>. Maybe that is just what List<Object?> means in Dart, and thus that is the best practice, but just feels odd to me.

@LuanNico I'm not following.  The caller decides what element type to use.  If they want a more specific element type, then they should List<int> or List<String> or whatever.  If they want to store heterogenous types, then they should use the nearest common base type, which might be List<Object> (or List<Object?> if null elements are allowed).  So yes, List<Object?> does mean that elements could be of type int or String or Null.

In this case the caller doesn't know or care what is the type of the Box (see the example of the BoxDumper). It could be Object?, meaning a box that can hold anything, or int, meaning a box that can hold only an int. These are different types of Box. The box dumper wants to accept any of them. So basically Box<*> or Box<? extends Object?>

There is a subtle difference between dynamic and Object?. From the latest Dart language spec section 20.7:

The type dynamic is a static type which is a supertype of all other
types, just like Object, but it differs from other types in that the
static analysis assumes that every member access has a corresponding
member with a signature that admits the given access.

void main(List<String> args) {
  final d = [];
  final o = <Object?>[];

  d.add(Object());
  o.add(Object());

  d[0].missingMethod(); // Will cause a NoSuchMethodError at runtime. 
                        // NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Object' has no instance method 'missingMethod'.

  o[0].missingMethod(); // Analyzer flags the missing method.  
}


Good point! That's the only difference I could notice, when "taking" elements. But the first one will also be flagged at compile time with:
Method invocation or property access on a 'dynamic' target.
Try giving the target a type. (dart: avoid_dynamic_calls)

Which will be marked as an error on my build. So both would not be allowed in the codebase and fail at compile time. Which still leaves me wondering which version should I opt for.

I think the difference is, that you can disable the linter rule if you really have to use dynamic. For example, the dart:convert package contains some instances of: // ignore: avoid_dynamic_calls to locally disable the linter rule.
